# Bootstrap CSS designing div boxes - centering issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I'm trying to design text boxes: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e08v0mbg/1/). I want them to be centered, but I can't get them to appear in the center of the page when they are next to one another. I would really appreciate your help!

```css
    .bottomboxes {
        border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
        -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        background: #aaaaaa;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 200px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    .rightbox {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 bottomboxes">
        <h3>text</h3>
        <p>more text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 bottomboxes rightbox">
        <h3>text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I suggest you edit your post and ask one question at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **CSS Flexbox** but then you don't need to use bootstrap 3 classes with `bottomboxes` with `col-sm-1`.

Checkout the updated **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e08v0mbg/2/)** (jsFiddle).

Something like:

```
/* Parent (replaced with .row) */
.content-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Childs (removed .col-sm-1) */
.bottomboxes {
  flex: 1; /* both should be of equal size */
}

/* Styling Resets */
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

---

**To make it mobile responsive:**

You need the textboxes to be on top and bottom. For that use mobile media query. Checkout this **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoxQaw)**.

It should look like:

```
/* On Mobiles (i.e. screen-width < 768px) */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .content-holder {
     flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! will this make my site less responsive though?

Comment: It actually works really well and solves all my problems, BUT the text boxes stay next to one another even on tiny screens, so I think I prefer to stick with the Bootstrap grid system. Is there any way to achieve this effect within the grid system?

Comment: @user3504783 Yeah! for that you need to apply mobile media query, check my updated answer.

Comment: @user3504783 My pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

You can change col-sm-2 to col-md-6 for both divs and they will appear next to each other. Like so:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 bottomboxes">
    <h3>text</h3>
    <p>more text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 bottomboxes rightbox">
    <h3>text</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I get them centered?